# Find a value in JSON file in Qt

Tags: json, algorithm, qt

I have a JSON file such like:

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "key": "8abd1c8c95f9f9c0f1c6d71e6cdece24",
      "val": "name1"
    },
    {
      "key": "f16d8c8d4163345bae5f5044d9ae7772",
      "val": "name2"
    },
    {
      "key": "9fa4b9915c6bae745f9400e08b391a6f",
      "val": "name3"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

and I want to search for the name (e.g. `name3`) and want to know the key (e.g. `9fa4b9915c6bae745f9400e08b391a6f`). How can I do this very fast in Qt with a recursive function?

Thanks

Comment: I have updated my original answer to cover the case you mentioned about looking for several values.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. An easy way to do it is using the [`QJsonDocument`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html) (available since Qt 5) and a basic linear search (I'm not sure why you are asking for a recursive function, which seems very less efficient, at least for the sample data structure you've provided).

The following snippet assumes the validity of the document (i.e., no error checking).

```
// 'text' is a variable containing the JSON data, probably read from a file
const QString text = R"({
    "entries": [
      {
        "key": "8abd1c8c95f9f9c0f1c6d71e6cdece24",
        "val": "name1"
      },
      {
        "key": "f16d8c8d4163345bae5f5044d9ae7772",
        "val": "name2"
      },
      {
        "key": "9fa4b9915c6bae745f9400e08b391a6f",
        "val": "name3"
      }
    ]
  })";

// Parse the document
const auto json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(text.toUtf8());

const auto entries = json["entries"];
for (const auto entry: entries.toArray()) {
  const auto obj = entry.toObject();
  if (obj["val"] == "name3") {
    qDebug() << "Key is" << obj["key"];
    break;
  }
}
```

Note that each entry of the JSON is treated as a generic `QJsonValue` which you have to convert to its actual type (`QJsonArray`, `QJsonObject`...).

#### Update

If you need to look up several values, you can consider preprocessing the JSON into a more efficient data structure like a map, and then perform your queries there, instead of iterating linearly on the document. Note that in this case we are assuming the values are unique to construct the *inverse map*, so the key is the value of the JSON, and the value is the key.

```
QMap<QString, QString> inv_map;
const auto entries = json["entries"];
for (const auto item : entries.toArray()) {
  const auto obj = item.toObject();
  inv_map[obj["val"].toString()] = obj["key"].toString();
}

QStringList names = {"name2", "name3", "name1"};
for (const auto &name : names) {
  const auto it = inv_map.find(name);
  if (it != inv_map.end()) {
    qDebug() << "Key for" << name << "is" << it.value();
  }
}
```

Further options include storing the list in a sorted array (sorted by value) and use a binary search to search for the entry with the value you want. This solution has the advantage that, if you have repeated values, you can still get the keys for all of them.